# How to pass parameters to a Servlet from JSP using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

Below is the code that I have written for creating an array of circular buttons and these buttons are given a value dynamically. These buttons gets deleted on click and the corresponding values of the buttons are passed to an array Object inside java script. Now my requirement is to send these value(deleted button values) as a whole to a servlet i.e when i complete my task (could be after deleting a button, or two button).

To realize this my i created another button after the div and included the entire body in form and with a name = deletedItems. But just on clicking any button the code is getting refreshed this because of the form. Can anyone suggest me how do I proceed? 
Note: I have not included the div part and the form part in this code below as that process was not working.

**Code**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr=new Array();

function hButton(id)
{             
document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("style","background:white");
//document.getElementById(id).disabled=true;
//arr[arr.length+1]=id;
arr.push(id);
document.getElementById("id-show").textContent=arr+"</br>";
}


function showId(id)
{
   document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("title",id);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <div id="big_wrapper">

<table>
<%for(int j=1;j<=3;j++){ %>
<tr>
<%for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){ %>

    <td>    <button class="btn"  style="background:red" id="<%=j%>,<%=i%>" onmouseOver='showId(this.id)' onclick='hButton(this.id)'> </button>  </td>

<%} %>
</tr>   
<%} %>
</table>

</div>
  <div id="id-show">
</div>    </body> </html>
```

---

Main.css file

```
.btn{

display:block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
border: 2px solid #f5f5f5;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.btn:hover {
opacity:0.9;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:700;
background: #262626;
}

#big_wrapper{
border:1px solid black;
width:1000px;
margin:20px auto;
text-align:left;
}

.theText{
opacity:0;
}

.btn:hover .theText
{
 opacity:0.9;
 color:#FFFFFF;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:700;
 background: #262626;
}


#some-element {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
display: none;
font-size: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

 #some-div:hover #some-element {
display: block;
 }
```

Comment: Did you tried using Ajax to send values to Servlet ?

Comment: No I haven't tried that. If  you are able to give me a hint as to how this can be implemented using Ajax, then I would love to.

Comment: Collect all deleted button values and store in array,dont use form, since button inside form will look for form action, outside form make an button element and in onclick pass the array as parameter to  javascript function, to help you start with please see the link http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/

Comment: Surely I will try that.. but do  you know any means where I can pass a value or parameter from javascript to outside?

Comment: What you mean by outside ?

Comment: Look in my above code I have created an Array variable(arr) inside javascript. Now If I try creating a ArrayList object inside a scriptlet, which is outside java script. Is there any means that I can  pass the Array variable to javascriptlet. I am sorry i am not able to convey it more clearly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55387/discussion-between-user2900314-and-sanr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below:

In JSP:

```
<script>
function submit() {
   var someVariable = "value to pass to server";
   document.getElementById("someFieldId").value = someVariable;
   document.form[0].submit();
}
</script>
<form name="someForm" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="someField" id="someFieldId" />
  <input type="button" name="Submit" onclick="submit()" />
</form>
```

In Servlet:

```
String variable = request.getParamater("someField");
```